# build/install succeed, but at runtime: dyld image not found - why?

Tags: osx-mountain-lion, icu, dyld

I had [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611740/qt-mac-osx-10-8-dyld-library-not-loaded-image-not-found) with ICU in my app, trying to run in Qt Creator on my Mountain Lion MacBook Pro.

Now I discovered I have a similar problem at run time with a dmg that I build on this same MacBook Pro.  The build completes successfully, running the dmg and installing appears successful, but when I try to run I get:

```
Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @executable_path/../Frameworks/libicuuc.46.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/MapCreator.app/Contents/SharedLibraries/libicui18n.46.1.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

I grabbed a previous tagged version of our app (and build script) from source control and I get the same problem when it's built on this MacBook.

The only errors I see when I run the build script are listed below.  I believe these errors have always been present in our builds on all machines, and have never been a problem, but I list them here just in case it turns out to be helpful:

```
ERROR: "strip: can't map file: /Users/david/dev/svn/map_creator1.0.2/build/mac/pkg-root/Applications/MapCreator.app/Contents (Invalid argument)
" 
ERROR: "" 
ERROR: "install_name_tool: can't map file: /Users/david/dev/svn/map_creator1.0.2/build/mac/pkg-root/Applications/MapCreator.app/Contents/Frameworks//.. (Invalid argument)
" 
ERROR: "" 
ERROR: "otool: can't map file: /Users/david/dev/svn/map_creator1.0.2/build/mac/pkg-root/Applications/MapCreator.app/Contents/Frameworks//.. (Invalid argument)
" 
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libicui18n.46.dylib" 
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libicuuc.46.dylib" 
ERROR: no file at "/usr/lib/libicudata.46.dylib"
```

I'm not sure where to look to track this down.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Does `libicuuc.46.dylib` exist inside MapCreator.app? If so, at what path?

Comment: yes, it's in Contents/SharedLibraries, with the other ICU dylib's.  SharedLibraries is a sibling of Frameworks.  By the way, that's the same place it is in an earlier version of our app.  It has never been in Frameworks as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently there is something different about the ICU install on my MacBook.  The problem is solved by adding more `install_name_tool -change` lines to our script, to change where it's looking for dependencies for the ICU files in question.

The format is:

```
install_name_tool -change old new file
```

If the "old" path doesn't match, it just ignores the command.  So simply adding the new lines covers the bases of various possible ICU installs.