# QtCreator for iOS: How to deploy a dylib shared library with my application

Tags: c++, ios, qt, qt-creator, dylib

I'm having a hard time deploying dynamic shared libraries on iOS.

To isolate and expose the problem, I have a very simple "HelloWorld" project: A library exporting class with a function returning "Hello World" and a program using the class and displaying the message.

I'm using QtCreator with Qt 5.5.

I'm able to generate the `.dylib` file and link my program. But, when I deploy it on the iPhone, I get the error:

```
Démarrage des processus distants.
dyld: Library not loaded: libMyLib.1.dylib
  Referenced from: /private/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/D6942CCE-828D-4C10-86DA-F7DA7ADF7449/MyApp.app/MyApp
  Reason: image not found
```

On Android, I had the same kind of issue and could fix it by manually adding the shared library to the final package (apk) file, using `ANDROID_EXTRA_LIBS`. But I can find no equivalent for iOS.

Here are my .pro files. Full project can be downloaded [here](https://bugreports.qt.io/secure/attachment/51438/bug_dylib.zip). I reported this to [Qt as a bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-15135), but if one could propose a kind of workaround this would help!

**MyLib.pro:**

```
QT       -= core gui

TARGET = MyLib
TEMPLATE = lib

DEFINES += MYLIB_LIBRARY

SOURCES += mylib.cpp

CONFIG += shared

HEADERS += mylib.h\
        mylib_global.h
```

**MyApp.pro:**

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = MyApp
TEMPLATE = app


SOURCES += main.cpp\
        dialog.cpp

HEADERS  += dialog.h

INCLUDEPATH += ../MyLib

LIBS += ../MyLib/libMyLib.dylib
```

I'd like the solution to be all embedded in QtCreator. The only think that should be changed here is one of the two .pro files. Possibly with post-build calls to MACOS commands...? Or just a post-build instruction in MyApp.pro to copy the dylib in the right place (.app target folder) before application is deployed? I'm really surprised this is not covered silently by QtCreator....

Note: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13611740/qt-mac-osx-10-8-dyld-library-not-loaded-image-not-found) suggests to set `DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH`. But I have no clue hox to do this within the MyApp.pro file nor how it will help upon iOS deployment (as DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH can be set the MAC PATH to the lib, not the iPhone PATH to the lib...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) In your library project make sure your dylibs have installname `@rpath/mylib.dylib` or such. E.g. by adding `QMAKE_SONAME_PREFIX = @rpath` to your library .pro file.
(You can check by looking at the first line of `otool -L /path/to/libmylib.dylib`. If the library is a prebuilt 3rdparty one, change it with `install_name_tool -id @rpath/libmylib.dylib`)

2) add the following to the application .pro file

```
# link to the lib:
LIBS += -L../mylib -lmylib
# make the app find the libs:
QMAKE_RPATHDIR = @executable_path/Frameworks
# deploy the libs:
mylib.files = $$OUT_PWD/mylib/libmylib.1.dylib
mylib.path = Frameworks
QMAKE_BUNDLE_DATA += mylib
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. It's been such a long time that I did not work on MacOS....I can't test your solution, but sure will when I get a chance to go back to this platform!

Comment: @jpo38 It works, I've just tested it. Please mark it as answer.

Comment: Note: Marked as accepted answer without testing myself

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a workaround for that, in case it could help anyone.

- Build your library statically instead of dynamically (replace `CONFIG += shared` by `CONFIG += staticlib`
- Now, compiler will generate `*.a` files instead of `*.dylib`, You must use this extension when linking libraries (replace `LIBS += myLib.dylib` by `LIBS += myLib.a`)
- If your library was only linked by a program, you are done
- If your library, let's call it (A), was used by another library (B), then (B) should not link with it anymore (No `LIB` flag in B.pro). Only the top level program will link with all your static libraries.

With this approach, I could deploy a program using 15 libraries on an iPhone with QtCreator.

Comment: What version of iOS are you targetting?